# Create a Passcode for windows mobile application

Tags: windows-phone-8, passwords

i Want to implement a passcode let say of 4 digits like we usually implement in Android. I know how to create it in android, but how can i make it done for windows phone 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by passcode? Do you want to implement it in your own application as a special login page or do you want to make it global for the entire phone?

If the former, simply create a special intro page.
If the latter, than it cannot be done at all since you do not have access to global functionality.

Comment: i want to make it as a special login page

Comment: Do you have any reference to source site where it has been done.

Comment: I don't have a link, but you could search for it. Do you know how to create pages in Windows Phone? Do you know how to do layout? Add controls on the page and perform page navigation?

Comment: yeah.. i do have a basic idea for this.

Comment: If you know all that stuff, creating a login page is a piece of cake :)

Comment: i have already done that... but i was looking for some measure that one box should contain 1 digit and then moves on the cursor to next.

Comment: Well, you are the programmer behind it, you can easily do that :D Just detect a string change in one box and focus on the next one. use `Focus` method to focus on a different text box.